# how to ask for username and password with a shell script on linux and windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell, posix

I need to ask for username and password from a .sh script for linux and windows, how is this possible?

i tried this but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Type the username, followed by [ENTER]:"

read username

echo "Type the password, followed by [ENTER]:"

read -s password

echo "The name entered was: $username"
echo "The path entered was: $password"
```

On linux and Windows terminal i get this:

```
>>bash try.sh

try.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
Type the username, followed by [ENTER]: 
try.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found      
': not a valid identifierername        
try.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found    
Type the password, followed by [ENTER]:       
try.sh: line 8: $'\r': command not found         
': not a valid identifierssword                
try.sh: line 10: $'\r': command not found         
The name entered was:                         
The path entered was:
```

Comment: You may have used an editor that puts `\r` chars in the script (like `notepad`). Do `dos2unix try.sh` to remove those and try running it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think your files have as line separators `\r\n`, which is vaid on windows but not on linux (at least for scripts intended to be read by bash). On linux the line separator should be `\n`